# Replace values of List<Class>

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have two `List<class>`, `List1` and `List2` which contains multiple columns: `RowNo`, `Value1`, `Value2`, etc.  as follows

**List1**

```
| RowNo | Value |
|-------|-------|
| 1     | 11    |
| 2     | 22    |
| 3     | 33    |
| 4     | 88    |
```

**List2**

```
| RowNo | Value |
|-------|-------|
| 1     | 44    |
| 2     | 55    |
| 3     | 66    |
```

I want to replace the value of element of `List1`  with the value of element of  `List2` if the `RowNo` matches.The output I want to generate is as follows

**Desired result**

```
| RowNo | Value |
|-------|-------|
| 1     | 44    |
| 2     | 55    |
| 3     | 66    |
| 4     | 88    |
```

Any Ideas or suggestions? How can I achieve this? What can be the best and efficient way to do this?

Comment: is your Class type is string ?

Comment: Is `RowNo` unique and act like Id?

Comment: I have Lists of Type List<ClassName>

Comment: @Pwavel002 I updated my answer to use linq

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a loop to compare the values in `List1` with `List2`, and if a match is found, update the `Value`

```
foreach (var item in List1)
{
    var match = List2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RowNo == item.RowNo);
    if (match != null)
    {
        item.Value = match.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq

```
List1.ForEach(l1 => l1.Value = (List2.FirstOrDefault(l2 => l2.RowNo == l1.RowNo) ?? l1).Value);
```

The `Value` property of `l1` list element will be set to itself if no element will be found on the `List2` list.

**Full code**

```
class MyClass
{
    public int RowNo { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

var List1 = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass(){RowNo = 1, Value = 11},
    new MyClass(){RowNo = 2, Value = 22},
    new MyClass(){RowNo = 3, Value = 33},
    new MyClass(){RowNo = 4, Value = 88},
};

var List2 = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass(){RowNo = 1, Value = 44},
    new MyClass(){RowNo = 2, Value = 55},
    new MyClass(){RowNo = 3, Value = 66}
};

List1.ForEach(l1 => l1.Value = (List2.FirstOrDefault(l2 => l2.RowNo == l1.RowNo) ?? l1).Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  List1.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var item = List2.FirstOrDefault(y => y.RowNo == x.RowNo);
            if (item != null)
            {
                x.Value = item.Value;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put all data of `list1` into a `Dictionary` (key is the RowNo).
2. Loop over `list2` to update the Dictionary.
3. Convert the data of the `Dictionary` to a `List`.

It approaches an O(n) operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension method to achieve what you want:

```
public static class LinqExtentions
{
    public static void Project<T>(this IEnumerable<T> lst1, IEnumerable<T> lst2,
        Func<T, object> key, Action<T, T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item1 in lst1)
        {
            var item2 = lst2.FirstOrDefault(x => key(x).Equals(key(item1)));
            if (item2 != null)
            {
                action(item1, item2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
List1.Project(List2, x => x.RowNo, (y, z) => { y.Value = z.Value; });
```

**What it does**

is projecting one list over the other, then matching the key values in both (`RowNo` in your example), when two items have the same key then the action supplied in the third parameter is applied, in this example, you want elements in the first list to have the same `Value` as elements in the second list, that's exactly what this delegate does:

```
(y, z) => { y.Value = z.Value; }
```

you can use this extension method to achieve the same requirement for any pair of lists:

1. Call `Project` on the list you want to change.
2. Pass the the list of the values you want to assign to the first list, as the first parameter.
3. Pass the key property as the second parameter.
4. The third 
   parameter is the action you want to apply on your list.

Answer (score -1):

You can loop over `List1` and check if `List2` contains a match then fill the result in a new list

```
List<YourClass> result = new List<YourClass>();
for (int i = 0; i < List1.Count; i++)
{
    YourClass resRowValue = List1[i];
    if (List2.Count > i && List2[i].RowValue.equals(resStrRowValue.RowValue)
        resStr.RowValue = List2[i].RowValue;

    result.Add(resRowValue);
}
//set the result to List1
List1 = result;
```

You can do this also using linq

```
List1 = List1.Select(x => {
    int i = List1.IndexOf(x);

    YourClass newValue = List2.FirstOrDefault(y => y.RowValue.Equals(x.RowValue));
    if (newValue != null)
        x.RowValue = newValue.RowValue;

    return x;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: `|` is not part of the object, it's for demonstration only

Comment: @MohamedElshawaf fixed

Comment: Can we achieve this using Linq instead of  looping? Also The Lists have many more columns not just two columns but i have to replace only one column values.

Comment: @Pwavel002 check my answer now